# Does anyone know why MSVC 2022 hasn't std::byteswap?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

Does anyone know why MSVC 2022 hasn't std::byteswap<>() ? I switched to C++20 compiling and everything I use from  works - but not std::byteswap<>(). Am I missing here stomething to make this work ?

Comment: Probably because [std::byteswap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/byteswap) from C++23 isn't in MSVC yet.

Comment: it's in [VS 19.31](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: @phuclv • Thanks, I was just going to link to that! [`/std:c++latest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170) to enable the C++23-isms that are in VS.  There is [`__cpp_lib_byteswap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/feature_test) available for feature testing.

Comment: How shall people on StackOverflow know Microsoft product-internal reasons? Maybe they didn't have time to implement it? Maybe they implemented it but they didn't release it because it does not pass unit tests? In the past, MS wasn't the fastest to implement, IMHO.

Comment: @ThomasWeller in this case they don't implement it simply because it's not in C++20. They already implemented in C++23

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/7KGznreME

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not part of C++20. It was only introduced in the current draft for C++23.

Even in a (pre-)C++23 mode, it shouldn't be expected that the compiler already implements all features of an unfinished standard revision and if it does implement them they should probably be considered experimental.

In this case, the latest MSVC has it available in `/std:c++latest` mode.